# to give transition effect to dropdown while in mobile view

Tags: html, css, menu

I want to try dropdown transition effect in my website. I have tried giving

```
transition: all 2s ease-in-out
```

but it does not give result. I want to show dropdown while in hover in mobile view with some transition effect. I am currently using some of the class of bootstrap.
Here's my HTML

```
                <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->

                    <div class="navbar-header pull-left">
                      <!-- <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                      </button> -->
                      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#" rel="home" title="Swiss-Japanese Society – www.swiss-japan.ch">
                    <img src="bild/Schweizerisch-Japanische-Gesellschaft.png" class="img-responsive showabove"></a>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#" rel="home" title="Swiss-Japanese Society – www.swiss-japan.ch">
                    <img src="bild/logomiddle.png" class="img-responsive showinbetween"></a>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#" rel="home" title="Swiss-Japanese Society – www.swiss-japan.ch">
                    <img src="bild/logosmall.png" class="showless"></a>

                    </div>
                    <div class="navbar-header pull-right">
                      <ul class="nav pull-left">
                        <!-- <li class="navbar-text pull-left">User Name</li> -->
                       <li class="dropdown pull-right">
                         <div id="lang_sel"><ul><li><a href="#" class="lang_sel_sel icl-de">DE</a> <ul><li class="icl-en"><a href="#">EN</a></li></ul></li></ul><span class="sj-down-arrow">▾</span></div>                            </li>
                      </ul>

                      <!-- Required bootstrap placeholder for the collapsed menu -->
                      <button type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" class="navbar-toggle"><span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span></button>
                    </div>

                <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
                    <div class="navbar-collapse navbar-right collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false" style="height: 21px;">


                               <ul id="menu-menu-1" class="nav navbar-nav"><li id="menu-item-20" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-12 current_page_item menu-item-20"><a href="#">Startseite</a></li>
          <li id="menu-item-580" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-580"><a href="#">Uber Uns</a>
     <ul class="sub-menu">
<li id="menu-item-175" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-175"><a href="#">Ziel und Zweck</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
    <li id="menu-item-226" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-226"><a href="#">testing</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-183" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-183"><a href="#">Leitbild</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-204" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-204"><a href="#">Entstehungsgeschichte</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-219" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-219"><a href="#">Vorstand</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-218" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-218"><a href="#">Aktueller Jahresbericht</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-217" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-217"><a href="#">Archiv Jahresberichte</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-581" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-581"><a href="#">Veranstaltungen</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
<li id="menu-item-248" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-248"><a href="#">Jubiläum 2014</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-245" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-245"><a href=#">Aktuelle Veranstaltungen</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-247" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-247"><a href="#">Vergangene Veranstaltungen</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-246" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-246"><a href="#">Fotogalerie</a></li>
 </ul>
 </li>
 <li id="menu-item-582" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-582"><a href="#">Mitgliedschaft</a>
 <ul class="sub-menu">
<li id="menu-item-232" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-232"><a href="#">Aufnahme-Bedingungen</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-233" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-233"><a href="#">Beitrittsgesuch</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-50" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-50"><a href="#">Varia</a></li>
 <li id="menu-item-40" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-40"><a href="#">Links</a></li>
 <li id="menu-item-30" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-30"><a href=#">Kontakt</a></li>
 </ul>             
                            </div>

            </div>

        </div>
```

sorry for my language. Can someone tell me in which class should i need to give transition so that to make the dropdown while in hover or while in clicked action.

below is css for dropdown class called `sub-menu`:

```
@media (max-width: 900px)
  .navbar-nav ul {
    position: static;
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    margin: 0;
    background: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    display: none;
  }

@media (max-width: 900px)
  .navbar-nav {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;    width: 100%;
    z-index: 10;
    background: #f8f6f6;
    overflow: visible;
  }

@media (max-width: 900px)
  .navbar-nav li {
    background: #fff;
    position: static;
    display: block;
    float: none;
    border: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
    border-top: 1px solid #999;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because bootstrap gives you dropdown which is `display:none` by default and on hover it is `display:block` but according to css rule `transition` property doesn't works on show hide condition.

You have to create your own dropdown with some other effect or you can use a plugin.

Comment: I have given my own class called `sub-menu`

Comment: is the condition same as i am saying...initially div is `display:none` and on hover its `display:block`?

Comment: yea dropdown appers but cant give a transition effect to make it slowly appear

Comment: thats what i am saying na that you cant give transition to hide show condition...

Comment: you can use `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut()` function from jquery i think this will be the most relevant thing here